# Stereo rectification with OpenCV 4.2.0

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, stereo-3d

I already do rectification with my own code. Now I am trying to make `cv2.stereoRectify` work.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread(IMG_LEFT) # Load image left
img2 = cv2.imread(IMG_RIGHT) # Load image right

A1 = np.array(A1) # Left camera matrix intrinsic
A2 = np.array(A2) # Right camera matrix intrinsic

RT1 = np.array(RT1) # Left camera extrinsic (3x4)
RT2 = np.array(RT2)  # Right camera extrinsic (3x4)

# Original projection matrices
Po1 = A1.dot( RT1 )
Po2 = A2.dot( RT2 )

# Camera centers (world coord.)
C1 = -np.linalg.inv(Po1[:,:3]).dot(Po1[:,3])
C2 = -np.linalg.inv(Po2[:,:3]).dot(Po2[:,3])

# Transformations
T1to2 = C2 - C1 # Translation from first to second camera
R1to2 = RT2[:,:3].dot(np.linalg.inv(RT1[:,:3])) # Rotation from first to second camera (3x3)
```

Then, I would like to find the rectification transformations (3x3). Following the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga617b1685d4059c6040827800e72ad2b6) I am trying:

```
Rectify1, Rectify2, Pn1, Pn2, _, _, _ = cv2.stereoRectify(A1, np.zeros((1,5)), A2, np.zeros((1,5)), (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]), R1to2, T1to2, alpha=-1 )


mapL1, mapL2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(A1, np.zeros((1,5)), Rectify1, Pn1, (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]), cv2.CV_32FC1)
mapR1, mapR2 = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(A2, np.zeros((1,5)), Rectify2, Pn2, (img2.shape[1], img2.shape[0]), cv2.CV_32FC1)

img1_rect = cv2.remap(img1, mapL1, mapL2, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
img2_rect = cv2.remap(img2, mapR1, mapR2, cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```

Anyway I am getting totally screwed images, surely not rectified. What am I doing wrong?
I guess it is something about rotations/translations, but I cannot figure it out.

Also, is OpenCV a bit overcomplicated about this? It should be an easy operation anyway.

Many thanks.

**EDIT:**
You may notice that I set distortion parameters to zero. That is because I am using computer generated stereo images that have no lens distortion.

Comment: Can you post some of your results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging into OpenCV documentation I found the reason why `stereoRectify()` does not seem to work.

Most of research paper often refer to *homography transformation* to be applied to the image.
OpenCV, instead, is computing the *rotation in the object space* as it is (shyly) explained in the `cv2.initUndistortrectifyMap()` documentation (see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga7dfb72c9cf9780a347fbe3d1c47e5d5a)).

So after calling:

```
R1, R2, Pn1, Pn2, _, _, _ = cv2.stereoRectify(A1, np.zeros((1,5)), A2, np.zeros((1,5)), (img1.shape[1], img1.shape[0]), R1to2, T1to2, alpha=-1 )
```

To get the rectification transformations I use:

```
Rectify1 = R1.dot(np.linalg.inv(A1))
Rectify2 = R2.dot(np.linalg.inv(A2))
```

Where `R1` and `R2` are the transformations output of OpenCV and `A1` and `A2` are the 3x3 camera matrices (intrinsics).

It seems to work just fine. Please comment if you have any better idea.

Hope this to be useful for anyone.